# Display header containing 3 columns in ListView

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am completely new to react native and am creating an application where I need to display items in a ListView.My ListView consists of 3 columns namely, author, title, price i.e. each row in ListView displays these three columns.Currently I am able to display only one column both in header section and the content section as

```
_renderRow(rowData){
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.row}> {rowData.title}</Text>
        </View>
    )
},

_renderHeader(){
    return (
        <View style={styles.sectionDivider}>
            <Text style={styles.headingText}>
                Title
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
},
```

And my render function is as

```
render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicatorIOS
                animating={this.state.isLoading}
                size="large">
            </ActivityIndicatorIOS>
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this._renderRow}
                renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

So, I want to render 3 columns both in header as well as in content section.I googled it but could not find any relevant content.

Comment: The rendering tools are very versatile and can do it in many ways, but from your code it looks like you didn't try to render more than one column. I suggest you try to do it and if it doesn't work, start a new question with your more specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily creating columns can be done with the flexbox style properties. For example:

```
_renderRow(rowData){
  return(
    <View styles={styles.flexRow}>
        <Text>{rowData.title}</Text>
        <Text>{rowData.author}</Text>
        <Text>{rowData.price}</Text>
    </View>
  )

_renderHeader() {
  return(
    <View styles={styles.flexRow}>
        <Text>Title</Text>
        <Text>Author</Text>
        <Text>Price</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flexRow: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'     <---- This is the important style property
  },
})
```

I created a snippet at https://rnplay.org/apps/p5hzcg if you want to play around with a working example.

Comment: ok thnx I figured that out already ... But anyway thnx for the answer

Answer (score -1):

you should try to modify your code with something like

`_renderRow(rowData){
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.column1}> {rowData.text1}</Text>
            <View style={styles.sectionDivider}>
            <Text style={styles.column2}> {rowData.text2}</Text>
            <View style={styles.sectionDivider}>
            <Text style={styles.column3}> {rowData.text3}</Text>
        </View>
    )
},
_renderHeader(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.column1}>textColumm1</Text>
        <View style={styles.sectionDivider}>
        <Text style={styles.column2}>textColumm2</Text>
        <View style={styles.sectionDivider}>
        <Text style={styles.column3}>textColumm2</Text>
      </View>
    )
},`

in this way each line will have 3 elements with same style, and if you fix the width of them it'll be exactly like columns.
Embedding text could alter the width value, so you have to decide what to do if the text is too long. So mostly deciding if to resize the text or going multiline.